# If the absolute value of a function is Riemann Integrable, then is the function itself integrable?

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to check the converses of a few theorems.

I know that that if $g$ is integrable then $|g|$ is integrable. However, if $|g|$ is Riemann Integrable, then is $g$ Rieman integrable?

I know that if $g$ is integrable then $g^2$ is integrable. However, is the converse true?

I have a hunch that they aren't true, but am failing to device the counter examples.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $f(x)=1$ when $x$ is rational, $-1$ when $x$ is irrational. Interval say $[0,1]$.

Comment: Notice that this example extends to Lebesgue integration by taking the characteristic of a non-measurable set.

Comment: @JacobSchlather: Thanks for the answer. By non-measurable set, do you mean uncountable sets? Also, I was wondering whether you had anything to say about the other question about :  know that if $g$ is integrable then $g^2$ is integrable. However, is the converse true? If no, why?

Comment: The example above takes care of your other question, since for the $f$ used in my answer, and Peter L. Clark's, has the property that $f^2=1$.  So if you take that as $g$, then $g^2$ is Riemann integrable but $g$ is not.

Comment: @user43901 That's not what I meant, although non-measurable sets are necessarily uncountable. If you haven't studied measure theory yet, I wouldn't worry about it. I was making a remark at the utility of the counterexample.

Comment: Non-measurable and uncountable are quite different. It so happens that every countable set is Lebesgue measurable. But plenty of uncountable ones are also, like any interval (open or closed), any countable union of intervals, many others.

Comment: Ah I think I see it now. The same example works. For $g^2$ gives us the same result as $|g|$, right? The values end up being positive for all $x$ in the interval $[0,1]$

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I can see a pattern developing now. Please let me know if I am just creating things. It appears that if $g^n$ where $n$ is even and $g^n$ is Riemann Integrable then $g$ is NOT integrable. Otherwise, if $n$ is odd, then it is integrable. For instance if $g^3$ is integrable, then $g$ is integrable. Proof: we know that $\beta: y \rightarrow y^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is continuous; thus if you compose $\beta$ with $g^3$, then we have $g$ to be integrable, right?

Comment: You are right about $g^n$ when $n$ is odd. Note that by the same reasoning, if $f(x)\ge 0$ on our interval, and $g^2(x)$ is Riemann integrable on that interval,  so is $g(x)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: but does my mini proof work for the $n$ odd case? Just making sure that my reasoning for the claim is rational.

Comment: Sorry, by you are right I meant your proof is correct.